# How to move/transform coordinates of WebGl tile in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, webgl, openlayers

I have a webapp showing base OpenStreetMaps layer and overlay layer of Geotiff with WebGLTile. The base map is in EPSG:3867 projection system, however the geotiff image in EPSG:32633 projection system. So the geotiff layer is rendered on the wrong place on the map. I figured out how to transcode the coordinates to the right system and show a marker where the image should be. But I can't figure out how to move or transform the overlay layer, so the geotiff will be in the right place? Can someone help me achieve this?

```js
const geotiffSource = new GeoTIFF({
    sources: [
        {
            url: "http://localhost:5173/odm_orthophoto_rgba.tif",
        },
    ],
});
let geotiffLayer = new WebGlTile({
    source: geotiffSource,
});
const view = new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
});
const map = new Map({
    target: "map",
    units: "m",
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        }),
        geotiffLayer,
    ],
    view: view,
});
```

The coordinates transformation:

```js
const lerp = (a, b, t) => (1 - t) * a + t * b;

    function transform(a, b, M, roundToInt = false) {
        const round = (v) => (roundToInt ? v | 0 : v);
        return [
            round(M[0] + M[1] * a + M[2] * b),
            round(M[3] + M[4] * a + M[5] * b),
        ];
    }

    const tiff = await fromUrl("http://localhost:5173/odm_orthophoto_rgba.tif");
    const image = await tiff.getImage();
    console.log(image);

    // Convert a GPS coordinate to a pixel coordinate in our tile:
    const [gx1, gy1, gx2, gy2] = image.getBoundingBox();
    const lat = lerp(gy1, gy2, Math.random());
    const long = lerp(gx1, gx2, Math.random());
    console.log(`Looking up GPS coordinate (${lat},${long})`);

    // Transform EPSG:32633 to EPSG:3857:
    // Define the projection for EPSG:32633 (UTM Zone 33N)
    proj4.defs(
        "EPSG:32633",
        "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
    );

    // Define the projection for EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator)
    proj4.defs(
        "EPSG:3857",
        "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
    );

    // EPSG:32633 coordinates
    epsg32633Coords = [long, lat];

    // Perform the coordinate transformation
    epsg3857Coords = proj4("EPSG:32633", "EPSG:3857", epsg32633Coords);

    console.log("EPSG:3857 Coordinates:", epsg3857Coords);

    // Add marker to map:
    const markerOriginal = new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(epsg32633Coords),
    });
    const markerNew = new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(epsg3857Coords),
    });

    const markerLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
            features: [markerOriginal],
        }),
    });
    const markerLayerNew = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
            features: [markerNew],
        }),
    });
    map.addLayer(markerLayer);
    map.addLayer(markerLayerNew);
```

Comment: It should be sufficient to define **and register** the UTM projection as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/multiple-cogs.html  EPSG:3857 is predefined in OpenLayers.

Comment: I've got it! Changing the TileLayer to WebGlTile layer help to render the geotiff correctly, but now I the zooming a moving on the map is restricted to the geotiff area, how can I prevent that? Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: You can use your own global view as in your code in the question if you wish, you do not need to base it on the source.